# IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo can not access a member of class with modifiers "public"

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to use choice and filter the object based on their properties but it could not access the getters and throwing error.Please help me to find the issue.

**Code:**

```
public class SampleTimerRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("timer:simpleTimer1?period=2000").process((exchange) -> {
            List<TestPOJO> names = new ArrayList<>();
            names.add(new TestPOJO("f1"));
            names.add(new TestPOJO("f2"));
            exchange.getOut().setBody(names);
        }).split(body(TestPOJO.class)).choice().when().simple("${body.getfName} == 'f1'").process((exchange) -> {
            exchange.getOut().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody(TestPOJO.class).getfName());
        }).to("file:output.txt?fileExist=Append").otherwise().to("stream:out");

    }
}

class TestPOJO {
    private String fName;

    public TestPOJO(String f) {
        fName = f;
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

}
```

**Log:**

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeExchangeException: IllegalAccessException occurred invoking method: public java.lang.String com.TestPOJO.getfName() using arguments: [] on the exchange: Exchange[]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:474) ~[camel-core-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:291) ~[camel-core-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:264) ~[camel-core-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:178) ~[camel-core-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109) ~[camel-core-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:69) ~[camel-core-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression$InvokeProcessor.process(BeanExpression.java:212) ~[camel-core-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression$OgnlInvokeProcessor.process(BeanExpression.java:323) ~[camel-core-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo can not access a member of class com.TestPOJO with modifiers "public"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:472) ~[camel-core-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The method is public but the class TestPOJO is not public and cannot be accessed normally by the Camel code. Make the class public.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks which is working, please answer with same content to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the method `getfName` is `public`, the class `TestPOJO` that contains the method has package-only access.

So it cannot be accessed by reflection from the Camel code (unless it uses `setAccessible(true)`, which it does not, as you have shown in the question).

Make the class TestPOJO `public` to resolve this problem.